# Node.js get full path from user input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, path

I'm trying to prompt the user to select a local folder with a `<input type="file"  webkitdirectory directory>` in order to get the fullpath to said folder, but the value comes out as `"C:\fakepath\folder"`

Apparently, the "fakepath" is here for security reasons, but my app involves helping the user find files within his personal folders... How could I do that with such security measures blocking my way?

I could ask the user to manually (copy/paste, type) enter the path... But some users could have a hard time figuring out what a "path" is, let alone understanding how to find it and retrieve it.

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you "prompt the user to select a local folder". E.G. do users download node and run your app or are you expecting to gain local file access from a web page?

Comment: Didn't know it would make any difference... Right now I've got node with an index.html file and a script.js (where all my functions are, appart from the main.js which only init the main window -aka, the index.html-).

I guess I'm prompting the user through a "web page" since it's a html/js file running in Electron/Chromium but... I thought since Node allowed local file reading/writing I would be able to get paths as well. 
Any module to achieve that?

Comment: In fact, I would distribute the app to be launched by the user (with node.js), so, not through a web page, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution with `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].files[0].path;` (my file input is the fourth one in my HTML file, thus [3], and since the input only allows one file (/or folder in this case) .files[0]).